# How to perform install only once under multiple stages?

Tags: travis-ci

I want to avoid perform install process times under multiple stages. My travis-ci config as follow, how to avoid run install process both in test and deploy stage? Beacause install is time-cost.

```
os: linux
language: android
licenses:
  - android-sdk-preview-license-.+
  - android-sdk-license-.+
  - google-gdk-license-.+
android:
  components:
  - tools
  - platform-tools
  - build-tools-28.0.3
  - android-28
jdk: oraclejdk8
sudo: false

install:
- git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable --depth 1
- export PATH=$PATH:./flutter/bin
- flutter doctor

cache:
  directories:
  - "$HOME/.pub-cache"

stages:
  - test
  - name: depoly
    if: tag =~ /^release-v\d+\.\d+\.\d+/ # tag match: release-v1.0.0

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test
    - script: flutter analyze lib/ test/
    - script: flutter test test/
    - stage: depoly
    - script: flutter build apk
      deploy:
        provider: releases
        api_key:
          secure: $github_deploy_api_key
        file: $APK_NAME
        skip_cleanup: true
        overwrite: true
        on:
          repo: stefanJi/Flutter4GitLab
          branch: master
```